# Red5 installation errorRed5 installation error

Tags: centos, red5

I am trying to instal red5 media server in centos 6. I followed many guides. But after installing java, apache-ant and after setting envirnmental variables, when i try to execute the commands ant prepare and ant dist. It shows errors.

Result of ant prepare

```
Buildfile: /usr/local/red5/build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.
```

Result of ant dist

```
Buildfile: /usr/local/red5/build.xml
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

-library.check:
     [echo] Java: java.home is /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.6.0-openjdk-1.6.0.0.x86_64/jre and the target version is 1.6
     [echo] Ant: ant.home is /usr/local/ant and the target version is Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013

-java6.check:
     [echo] Using Java 1.6 specification: 1.6

prepare:

compile:
     [echo] javac version: 1.6
     [echo] Not using the Eclipse IDE
     [echo] Compiler adapter name: modern
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

compile-core:
  [taskdef] Could not load definitions from resource org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml. It could not be found.

retrieve:

BUILD FAILED
/usr/local/red5/build.xml:225: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/red5/build.xml:239: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/usr/local/red5/build.xml:174: Problem: failed to create task or type antlib:org.apache.ivy.ant:settings
Cause: The name is undefined.
Action: Check the spelling.
Action: Check that any custom tasks/types have been declared.
Action: Check that any <presetdef>/<macrodef> declarations have taken place.
No types or tasks have been defined in this namespace yet

This appears to be an antlib declaration.
Action: Check that the implementing library exists in one of:
        -/usr/local/ant/lib
        -/root/.ant/lib
        -a directory added on the command line with the -lib argument


Total time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: Does the file `antlib.xml` exist anywhere on your system?

Comment: yes.it exists in /usr/src/ivy/doc/xooki/antlib.xml
/usr/src/ivy/src/java/org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml